# All my RAM is suddenly Hardware Reserved ! 256Mb available?

Tags: windows, memory, motherboard, compatibility

I have a desktop computer which worked perfectly for 5 years until yesterday. Over the 12Gb of *same & compatible* RAM installed, it suddenly can use only 256Mb, the remaining being 'Hardware Reserved' (Window's performance manager).

The specs are :

**Motherboard :** MSI H77MA-G43 (supports DDR3, up to 1600MHz https://www.cnet.com/products/msi-h77ma-g43-motherboard-micro-atx-lga1155-socket-h77/specs/)

**CPU :** Intel core i5 3300 K (more or less : bought it in 2013)

**GPU :** AMD Radeon HD 7700 (more or less : bought it in 2013)

**RAM :** 3x Ballistix Sports 1600 MHz 4Gb

**Storage :** HDD 1Tb (files) + SSD 256Gb (system)

**OS :** Windows 7 - Not recognizing activation key

***Recent changes :***

- Added the third memory stick (~ 2 months ago) but it didn't give me any trouble. Exact same model as the previous ones as far as I can tell.
- Cloned the system partition from my old HDD 5400 rpm to a new SSD (samsung PRO 256Gb).

***Other, possibly related issues :***

- The whole machine has traveled a lot by airplane i.e. it has been disassembled and reassembled many times (possibility of damage due to mechanical stress).
- The machine sometimes gets stuck before loading BIOS. Maybe correlated with the previous case.
- Windows activation key is not regognized anymore. While I remember trying to recover the key and put it back again, it didn't work. I don't even remember if I have a valid activation key or one from a keygen..

***What I tried :***

- System recovery
- Memtest (everything OK...)
- Kept only 1 memory stick (old one) and tried every slot
- Reset BIOS to default settings
- Ran msconfig and check that there was no maximum memory

So, given all these strange problems, my only guess is that my motherboard is dying.

Are there some more conclusive tests I could do ? I don't have much money and I don't want to buy a new motherboard if it's not necessary !

Thank you !!

EDITS : Should I try to update the BIOS ? I would like to keep the formatting+clean windows install as the last test, since it'll take much time.
(The is being constantly updated..)

Comment: Did you try to run some linux live disk or reinstall Windows?

Comment: No, I haven't. Is there a fastest way to check if it's the problem is from the OS ? Would running a windows repair or just start some installation tell me this ? It would be a lot of trouble for me to reinstall the OS (I have a lot of programs I could not recover easily...)

Comment: so what's wrong with trying linux live cd? that doesn't require you to install anything.

Comment: "*The system though, can only use 256Mb, regardless of how many memory sticks are installed and on which slot.*" Can you show us exactly how you determined this?

Comment: What word are you trying to use when you say "system recuperation"

Comment: @ David Schwartz : I simply looked at Window's system information, it says the amount of RAM installed and available. And it was quite obvious anyway that it was a RAM problem : games won't start because of the lack of memory, and the computer was really slow. I also tried to keep only 1 memory stick and switched it over all the slots, the problem persisted.

Comment: @ Ramhound : Sorry I am translating all these words from french. I meant system recovery (post edited for clarity).

Comment: When you mention someone, make sure there's no spaces in the name or after the at-sign, otherwise they won't be notified. (cc @DavidSchwartz, there's a reply to your comment above.)

Comment: @Tool So you looked at the Windows control panel that shows your CPU, RAM, system type, and so on? And under "Installed RAM", it said "256 MB"? Or what? Your question said the issue was Windows detecting 256 MB "available"? Did you mean installed? Can you please be incredibly specific about exactly what you're looking at and exactly what you're seeing?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : Please read again the post, I edited it for clarity. Windows Performance Manager shows that over 4gb (I am now trying 1 memory stick at the time) there are 256Mb available and the rest is Hardware Reserved.

Comment: I had an issue similar to this that was solved by using msconfig's max RAM option, or rather unselecting that option because I'd mistakenly done so. That may not have been your issue, but for those that have mistakenly done that, this comment resides for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers : Reinstalling the OS solved the problem. Cloning it caused me problems 2 months later, which I'd never think it would happen.

So I'll never clone my OS again ! When you buy a new drive, just reinstall everything on it.

Now I'll be struggling with windows activation key, since I don't have it anymore..

Comment: If you have Windows 8 or 10 you can login to the www.microsoft.com website and log-in to your Microsoft Account, and re-authorize your computer for use. This is how you can circumvent re-applying the authorization key if you lost it for some reason.

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't use a digital license like Windows 10 does.  Doesn't change the fact your (Windows 8 and Windows 10) license will automatically be detected though since they are stored in the ACPI table.